# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home/galaxy/public_html/writersPortal/php/connect.php on line 9

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

I have this code working so well in another server. But when I migrated the website to another server, I got this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home/galaxy/public_html/writersPortal/php/connect.php on line 9

This is the code:

```
      <?php

        ########## MySql details (Replace with yours) #############
        $username = "galaxy_writing"; //mysql username
        $password = "munywa1234$$"; //mysql password
        $hostname = "localhost"; //hostname
        $databasename = "galaxy_writing"; //databasename

       $link = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
       mysqli_select_db($link, $databasename)or die(mysql_error($link));




       ?>
```

Comment: mysqli probably isn't compiled into the server. Check `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Your `mysqli` php-extension  isnt installed.